# QPSQL Not always possible to accept an answer

Tags: postgresql, qt, qt5

The answer comes when using this form of request:

```
SELECT id FROM link WHERE uid_fl = '%1';
```

Otherwise it does not come:

```
auto db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
```

...

```
QSqlQuery query(db);
QString request = QString(
    "SELECT id FROM link WHERE uid_fl = '%1' AND end_fl IS NULL;"
            )
    .arg(is_uid);
query.exec(request);

while (query.next())
{
    qDebug() << "id" << query.record().value(0).toString();
}
```